# how to pass variable value from one method onto another as a parameter of database query in java

Tags: java

I have retrieved the value of logtime from database and calculated one hour ago time from the retrieved logtime.the code for retrieving logtime is

```js
public String database_Time() {



  try {
    con = getConnection();
    String sql = "select max(logtime) from vacuum_analog_1mins";

    clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql);

    clstmt.execute();
    rs = clstmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      timestr = rs.getString(1);

    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean in getDbTable(String code):" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection();
  }


  return timestr;
}
```

Code to calculate one hour ago time is:

```js
public Date previostime() throws ParseException
{
  database_Time();
 
  String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new       SimpleDateFormat(format);
  Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timestr);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(date);
  int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  hours--;
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
  Date fixedDate = calendar.getTime();

  System.out.println("previous date is" + (fixedDate));
  System.out.println("current date is" + timestr);
  return fixedDate;


}
```

Now I want to use these two variables fixedDate and timestr in my another method where these variables will be used as parameters of a sqlquery as:

```js
List < String > timeStr = new ArrayList < String > ();
database_Time();
String atime[] = null;
database_Time();
previostime();

getConnection();
try {
  con = getConnection();


  String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
 

  clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql);
  clstmt.setString(1, "vs1_bag");
  clstmt.setString(2, "fixedDate");
  clstmt.setString(3, "timestr");
  clstmt.execute();
  rs = clstmt.getResultSet();

  while (rs.next()) {
    // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
    timeStr.add(rs.getString(1).substring(11, 16));

  }
```

But no result.Please help me where I'm going wrong.I have declared these variables as global also.

Comment: fixedDate and timestr are set as variables class?

Comment: @Mailkov they are declared as variables      public Date fixedDate;
  public String timestr;

Comment: because i see that you declared fixedDate in your method previoustime()

Comment: Are they Date type in sql ?

Answer (score 0):

This two row aren't correct

```
clstmt.setString(2, "fixedDate");
clstmt.setString(3, "timestr");
```

if in sql they are Date type try this:

```
clstmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date(fixedDate.getTime()));
clstmt.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(timestr));
```

Comment: but you change  Date fixedDate = calendar.getTime(); in fixedDate = calendar.getTime(); in your previoustime() methos ?

Comment: Can You do write the value of timestr and fixedDate.toString() ?

Comment: timestr is already string type and I have written fixed date as fixedDate.toString() as you said.

Comment: Try this I change the fixedDate row